# How to get the keywords with best popularity on App Store Optimisation?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

My apps have good ratings (all of them >4/5), but I’m stuck at making their traffic significantly increase.

After having read many blog posts and other sources about ASO (App Store Optimization), I managed to successfully find some good words and long-tail keywords for my app.

I am also able to find some information to know how my app is currently ranking for a given search in a given country, thanks to Apple API (see https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api).

However, I can’t find any solution to keep only the most relevant of these keywords (with decent traffic and above all low competition).

If I was to find a great, free trial solution that would actually help me getting more traffic, I would seriously consider paying for it afterwards to stay competitive in ASO.

I tried to have a look at keywords popularity with a simple Google search, but I am convinced the way people look for apps is different from the way they use Google.

So I would like to know if any free tool really exists, or if Apple provides any API to get this data.

Comment: How precisely are you measuring traffic. I'm not going to -1 this, but it seems highly opinion based and unlikely to be something that is of long term value since what works now won't work in 3 months in marketing. Basically - are you looking for how to place paid ads with Apple or paid ads with something else?